# SKAction.sequence within and SKAction.sequence doesn't run

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am having a bit of a problem with this code. Inside didMove I am calling SKAction.sequence which runs fine, and creates the monsters.

However I want to be able to delete these monsters and am not being able to after a period of time.

I am calling addMonster() function and within it I have an SKaction.sequence call to fade out and remove the monsters. It doesn't seem to run though....

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

     run(SKAction.repeatForever(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.run(addMonster),
            SKAction.wait(forDuration: 5.0)
            //SKAction.run(addMonster),
            ])
    ))
}

func addMonster() {

    let monster = Enemy(enemySpriteName: "triangle", name: enemyName, 
    position: CGPoint(x: background.position.x + 300 + CGFloat(enemycount), 
    y: background.position.y + 50 + CGFloat(enemycount)), zPosition: 9)
     self.addChild(monster)
//This part doesn't seem to run ?!
    let scale = SKAction.scale(to: 0.1, duration: 2.5)
    let fade = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 3.5)
    let actionMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    monster.run(SKAction.sequence([scale, fade,  actionMoveDone]))
}
```

Comment: what version of iOS are you testing on?

Comment: Testing it on iOS 11.1.1

Comment: long shot but, at the end of didMove try adding ```self.isPaused = false```

Comment: unfortunately didn't seem to make a difference :(

Comment: where are you doing it at( I am assuming in your viewDidLoad which will not help)?  i would recommend trying `monster.isPaused = false` inside of your addMonster,

Comment: I added that in didMove first and then in addMonster. - I tried monster.isPaused and seems like no results still , that's strange. Because I know the code runs that.

Comment: @Marin The code you posted is correct (I tested it). So the issue is probably in some code you are not showing us.